# Sum horizontally with array

Tags: sas

Trying to use the following code to sum horizontally and create a dummy total. So, each variable in the array is a dummy flag. I want to count the number of dummy flags per row.

```
data rep;
    set clean;
    array missU (9) util_92013  util_32014  util_22014  util_72013  util_82013  util_12014  util_42014  util_122013 util_62014; 
    do i = 1 to 9;
        totalU = sum(of missU(i));
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

I continue getting `NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop.

```
data rep;
  set clean;
  array missU ... ;  
  totalU = sum(of missU[*],0);
run;
```

As user667489 pointed out in comments, adding a zero to the sum function will avoid a missing value being generated when *all* flags are missing (if that's desired).

Comment: Thanks, I tried something similar before, but the missU[*] was causing an error. I originally had the array titled 'miss_U'. COuld the '_' cause problems?

Comment: No, _ is a perfectly normal character in SAS.

Comment: @Joe - sum returns missing values if all inputs are missing. Adding zero works around this behaviour.